# Need to modify a jQuery accordion menu

Tags: jquery, if-statement, menu, accordion

Please see this menu: http://maxim.comze.com

The third button opens a sliding panel closes it, I'd like the other buttons to also close the panel if in case it was already open. I know this has something to do with add acitem and if/else statements, but I have no experience with those.
Much appreciated.

This is the menu code:

```
$('li hometog, li jredtog, li servicestog',this).click(function(e){       
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var theElement=$(this).next();
    var parent=this.parentNode.parentNode;

    if($(parent).hasClass('noaccordion')){
        if(theElement[0]===undefined){window.location.href=this.href}
        $(theElement).slideToggle('normal',function(){
            if($(this).is(':visible')){
            $(this).prev().addClass('active')
    }else{
        $(this).prev().removeClass('active')}});
        return false
    }else{
        if(theElement.hasClass('acitem')
        &&theElement.is(':visible')){if($(parent).hasClass('collapsible')){
           $('.acitem:visible',parent).first().slideUp('normal',function(){
               $(this).prev().removeClass('active')
           });
           return false
        }
    return false
    }

    if(theElement.hasClass('acitem')&&!theElement.is(':visible')){
          $('.acitem:visible',parent).first().slideUp('normal',function(){
               $(this).prev().removeClass('active')});

               theElement.slideDown('normal',function(){
                    $(this).prev().addClass('active')});

                     return false}
    }
}) 
})
};
```

This is the 3rd buttons' code:

```
$("servicestog").click(function(){
    $(".panel").toggle("slide",{direction: "right"},500);
    $(this).prev().addClass('active')
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I don't think you should be making up HTML element names like <servicestog>. Use a semanticly relevant element like <a> with a CSS class, e.g. <a class="servicestog">. That's unrelated to your question, just a comment on your markup.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind, but somehow I've never had problems with custom markups.

Comment: I don't think you can have 2 `else` statements in an `if/else`.  If needed you can make an `else if` and have a condition checked

Comment: Can you give an example how it can be done for this menu? That's what I am unable to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest solution to the is to have another function that is called when you click on one of the other menu items, that will hide the side panel if it is showing.  So, adding this:

```
// When clicking on 'hometog' or 'jredtog'
$('li hometog, li jredtog', this).click(function (e) {
    // if the panel is visible, hide it
    $('.panel:visible').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
});
```

Above your existing click handler:

```
$('li hometog, li jredtog, li servicestog', this).click(function (e) {
```

Gives the behaviour your after.

The problem with the way that the click handler has been built at the moment is that it fires whenever you click on any of the menu items (the ones that activate drop downs and the one that activates / hides the panel).  This means that at some point in the handler you would need to decide if the element that triggered the click handler was the one that showed the panel, so that you could decide if it needed hidden or not.

This could be done by adding something like this to your existing handler (before any of the branching logic):

```
if (!$(this).is('servicestog')) {
    $('.panel:visible').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
}
```

An alternate way to do it would be to add another class `activatesPanel` to the menu item that activates the panel:

```
<servicestog class="activatesPanel">Menu 3</servicestog>
```

Then you could do something like this in your existing handler:

```
if (!$(this).hasClass('activatesPanel')) {
    $('.panel:visible').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
}
```

There seems to be some logic that attempts to do something similar using the `acitem` and `active` classes, however it's not very clear how this logic is supposed to be working and it seems to fall down a bit with the panel.

Comment: The first option does the job just fine. Thanks you very much, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this does the trick for you?

```
$('li hometog, li jredtog, li servicestog',this).click(function(e){       
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
var theElement=$(this).next();
var parent=this.parentNode.parentNode;

if($(parent).hasClass('noaccordion')){
    if(theElement[0]===undefined){window.location.href=this.href}
    $(theElement).slideToggle('normal',function(){
        if($(this).is(':visible')){
        $(this).prev().addClass('active')
} else if(theElement.hasClass('acitem')&&theElement.is(':visible')){
       if($(parent).hasClass('collapsible')){
       $('.acitem:visible',parent).first().slideUp('normal',function(){
           $(this).prev().removeClass('active')
       });
       return false
    }
return false
}else{
    $(this).prev().removeClass('active')}});
    return false
}

if(theElement.hasClass('acitem')&&!theElement.is(':visible')){
      $('.acitem:visible',parent).first().slideUp('normal',function(){
           $(this).prev().removeClass('active')});

           theElement.slideDown('normal',function(){
                $(this).prev().addClass('active')});

                 return false}
}
}) 
})
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but there seems to be a syntax error somewhere I couldn't find it.